# ClassCastException Daterange[]

Tags: java, stream, resultset, classcastexception, date-range

I tried to transform a DateRange [] into an Array with streams, but it gives me a ClassCastException error

```
Array pgArray = rs.getArray("periodo_carica");
 periodo_carica = (DateRange[]) pgArray.getArray();
 List<DateRange> periodo_carica2 = new ArrayList<DateRange>();
 periodo_carica2 =
                 Arrays.stream(periodo_carica)
                 .map(DateRange2::getRange)
                 .filter(d -> DateRange2.getRange(d) != null)
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

OUTPUT:

```
Connected to PostgreSQL server successfully!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to 
 class [Lorg.jfree.data.time.DateRange; ([Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 
'bootstrap'; [Lorg.jfree.data.time.DateRange; is in module jfreechart@1.5.0 of loader 'app')
```

in my database in postgresql I have the table, in java in Eclipse I created the corresponding attribute DateRange[] that YOU TOLD ME TO SET AS OBJECT[] BUT it is DateRange[]

```
CREATE TABLE public.parlamentari
(
nome character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
partito character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
circoscrizione character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
data_nascita date,
luogo character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
titolo_studi character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
mandati character varying(1000)[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
commissioni character varying(100)[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
periodo_carica daterange[],
CONSTRAINT parlamentari_pkey PRIMARY KEY (nome, partito, circoscrizione),
CONSTRAINT parlamentarinomekey UNIQUE (nome)
 ,
CONSTRAINT parlamentaripartitonomekey UNIQUE (partito, nome)

 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

The error message tell us that the value returned from the `getArray()` call is an `Object[]`, not a `DateRange[]`. Sure, all the objects in the array might be `DateRange` objects, but the array component type is `Object`, not `DateRange`, so you'll have to cast twice.

```java
Array pgArray = rs.getArray("periodo_carica");
Object[] periodo_carica = (Object[]) pgArray.getArray(); // cast to Object[]
List<DateRange> periodo_carica2 = new ArrayList<DateRange>();
periodo_carica2 =
                Arrays.stream(periodo_carica)
                .map(o -> (DateRange) o) // cast each element to DateRange
                .map(DateRange2::getRange)
                .filter(d -> DateRange2.getRange(d) != null)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I tried a rate as you say but it tells me: periodo_carica = pgArray.getArray(); //Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to Object[] .....and if I declare:    Object periodo_carica; //i get another error:The method stream(T[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (Object) ....to line:  Arrays.stream(periodo_carica)

Comment: .map(o -> (DateRange) o) //Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.postgresql.util.PGobject cannot be cast to class org.jfree.data.time.DateRange (org.postgresql.util.PGobject is in module org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.18 of loader 'app'; org.jfree.data.time.DateRange is in module jfreechart@1.5.0 of loader 'app')
 at Servlet_Parlamento.Parlamentari.Tabella_Parlamentari.lambda$0(Tabella_Parlamentari.java:106)

Comment: @Marina So the array contains `PGobject` objects, not `DateRange` objects. Since we don't know your data model, we can't help with that.

Comment: in my database in postgresql I have the table, in java in Eclipse I created the corresponding attribute DateRange [] that YOU TOLD ME TO SET AS OBJECT [] BUT it is DateRange []

Comment: @Marina The error message said *"`Object[]` cannot be cast to `DateRange[]`"*, so it is obviously an `Object[]` that you got from the database when you called `getArray()`.

Comment: I understood where I was wrong: I have to convert the object to pgArray contained in DateRange[] and assign it to periodo_carica